# Tomcat Not starting up> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina

Tags: java, tomcat

I am unable to start the tomcat 5.5 server due to following error message in the stderr.log.
Can someone please help me, it is kind of emergency. Thanks in advance.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina   
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)   
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)   
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)   
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)    
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:222)   
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:410)
```

Comment: Have you set your Environment variables?

Comment: yes, below are the environment variables: Classpath: E:\Tomcat\Tomcat 5.5\bin\bootstrap.jar;E:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\jdbc\lib\ojdbc6.jar;E:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\jlib\orai18n.jar                                          JVM:E:\Java\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll                             Options: -Xmx1536m
-Xms1536m
-XX:MaxPermSize=120m
-XX:SurvivorRatio=4
-Ddatasource=oracle
-Dcatalina.base=E:\SmartOffice\Instances\TMGNEW
-Dcatalina.home=E:\Tomcat\Tomcat 5.5
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=E:\Tomcat\Tomcat 5.5\common\endorsed
-Djava.io.tmpdir=E:\SmartOffice\Instances\TMGNEW\temp

Comment: Add environment variable CATALINA_HOME with path to the location of Apache installation (or extracted folder location). For example: C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.56

Comment: Thanks, learningloop.

Comment: Now I am getting the another ejb exceptions; ava.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:                               javax/ejb/EJBException
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:620)

Answer (score 6):

I was facing the same issue. Then I noticed that I have accidentally deleted lib folder from tomcat directory. The issue got resolved as lib folder back in place.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I changed catatina.properties file found in tomcat_directory/conf from

```
common.loader='${catalina.base}/lib','${catalina.base}/lib/*.jar','${catalina.home}/lib','${catalina.home}/lib/*.jar'
```

To

```
common.loader=${catalina.base}/lib,${catalina.base}/lib/*.jar,${catalina.home}/lib,${catalina.home}/lib/*.jar
```

However the file always used to get overwritten. I was using eclipse. So, I did the same change in the Servers Project in eclipse. In my case it was Servers/Tomact v9.0 Server/catalina.properties. 
I did the same change stated above in this file too. It worked for me.

Comment: The reason your file was getting overwritten was neglecting to change the Server Location from "Use Tomcat Server location" to "Use workspace metadata"

Comment: Thanks a lot! It helped!!

Comment: Thanks. Just remember the comment in the catalina.properties file: `Values are enclosed in double quotes ("...") in case either the${catalina.base} path or the ${catalina.home} path contains a comma.`

Answer (score 3):

From my experience, I have observed that tomcat sometimes throws this when we keep on running server multiple times, this led server unable to pickup the jars
my suggestion is to **restart** the eclipse, this resolved my issue

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and stacktrace using 8.5.11 tomcat. updating to tomcat 8.5.24 solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat by default needs a set of libraries inside the lib folder to bootstrap the starting process inside the tomcat. Make sure you have these libs inside the lib folder. This is for tomcat8.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, I have observed that `tomcat` sometimes throws this when there are project dependent jars (could be transitively dependent as well) missing, or not being pointed to properly, or corrupted. So, please check the health of the jars deployed in the server and their dependencies. For example, if you are using `maven` to build your project jars, you could once clear the `.m2/repository` and rebuild the project and deploy again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was resolved by adding ejb.jar file into Tomcat/lib folder which is the dependency package to startup.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, even though all the necessary things are perfect, this error would be reported if there is user VM arguments enclosed with the double quotes, I spent a day to get rid of this. check in run --> run configuration, in arguments tab, VM Arguments, check for the user entries is enclosed with quotes/spaces, if so remove it and 'Run'

Answer (score 0):

Before I started the Tomcat Service, I updated a jar file in `tomcat/lib` path. With this probably I corrupted the file. Because when I move back original jar file in `tomcat/lib` I solved the problem. You also have to check `lib/*jar` files.